# growth function of f.g semigroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

In the paper of Alan J.Cain et al " Green index in semigroups: Generators, presentations, and automatic structures", is mentioned that if $T$is a finitely generated subsemigroup of a finitely generated(f.g)semigroup $S$, then if the growth function of $S$ is polynomially upper-bounded so will be the growth function of $T$. Also there is mentioned that in general the converse is not true! Can someone please explain this to me by an example, why this is not true?

ab

Comment: Let $F$ be a free group on two generators and $G$ a finite group.  Then $F\times G$ has exponential growth but the subsemigroup $G$ has growth bounded by a constant.

Comment: If you express the generators of $T$ as words in the generators of $S$ and if $N$ is the max length of a generator of $T$ as a a word in the generators of $S$, then each element of $T$ of length most  $k$ in the generators of $T$ can be expressed as a word in the generators of $S$ of length at most $kN$.  So if $T$ has super polynomial growth, then you can use this estimate to see that $S$ does as well.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Great. Thanks!